# I want to allow users to click "share this" on a page with an image, and then email that image as an attachment

Tags: webforms

I have a site that shows floor plans for houses. I want to allow users to share a floor plan via an email form where they can enter their email address and their friend's email address who they want to share with. Then when they enter their message and submit, the image of the floor plan will be attached to the outbound email from the server.

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for isn't a drag-and-drop sort of feature. It would require building a custom module. Are you asking how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Send feature in the [Printer, e-mail and PDF versions](http://drupal.org/project/print) Module. It will allow your user to send the page as rendered in HTML, attached images, and custom messages.

Comment: this may not be the perfect answer to the question, but it ended up being the solution my friend ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to write your own module, check out the [mimemail module](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail). Sending the mail is as easy as [this](http://api.lullabot.com/mimemail):

```
mimemail($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body, $plaintext = NULL, $headers = array(), $text = NULL, $attachments = array(), $mailkey = '')
```

If you store the picture in a imagefield or filefield inside a node, you can put that field into the attachments array and send it.